# How do I programmatically present a popover in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to present a UIViewController as a popover programmatically.

[image]

As you can see , the transition style is set to `Cross Dissolve` and the presentation is set to `Over current context`. So technically if I click the button, the transition will work, my goal is to do it programmatically.

```
func clickButton() {
     //What should I do here?   


 }
```

How do I present the popover programmatically on `clickButton`?

Comment: so you defined it in story board but want to let it view programatically? or want to code it and push it to view programatically?

Comment: Try one of these as well: https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/Presentrlog
https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are presenting view controller modally. You can do like this.

```
func clickButton() {
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_ID") {
        vc.modalTransitionStyle   = .crossDissolve;
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I pass the data?

Comment: is it `vc.profileImage` ? what if I want to pass data on a function on the `PopViewController` itself

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let rateViewController = RatePopupVC()
rateViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
rateViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(rateViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you want to close it programmatically

Inside PopupVC

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
func clickButton() {

    let vc : PopupVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopupVCID") as! PopupVC
    vc.modalTransitionStyle   = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
let popupview = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController")
popupview.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
self.addChildViewController(popupview)
self.view.addSubview(popupview.view)
popupview.didMove(toParentViewController: popupview)
```